# Field updates only if I update browser in dynamics crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I wrote plugin for CRM. It update field of `Entity A` when create a new `Entity B`. 
I have a form for `Entity A` and in this form I have tab for `Entity B`. When I create new `Entity B` from this tab my plugin change field in `Entity A`. But I can't see that change until I reload browser page.

[image: Adding entity B from tab]

[image: Saving entity B]

[image: Filed doesnt change until page will be reloaded]

Comment: This is expected behavior - the page wont force itself to reload unless you tell it to (call Xrm.Page.data.refresh()).  Even if you do refresh it, the value may not have been updated by the time you refresh the page (if the plugin is registered asynchronously).

Comment: What event should I use to call Xrm.Page.data.refresh()? My plugin is synchrounous.

Comment: Good question - plugins live server side, and you would need to call a client side event.  You could try to find the grid.refresh through F12 (for event responses) and override that to refresh the whole page instead of just the grid.

Comment: maybe you could add an onrefresh Event to the subgrid (the one where the + is above). in the callback you could refresh the current form like Joseph descriped. See this article: http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/07/bind-function-to-subgrid-refresh.html

Answer (score 1):

You're somehow losing sight of the fact that your plugin is running on the server, and it updates the data in the database on another server.  There is no built in method of having a database update trigger a notification on a particular client (or all).  Thus you have two options:

1. Trigger an Xrm.Page.data.refresh (or a save would work as well, since this will pull down new values) within the context of `Entity A`, after performing the save of `Entity B`.
2. Use polling and the CrmWebApi or odata endpoint to query CRM for that value updating on the server side, and then updating it on the client as well.

Your question was a little difficult to understand, but #1 may be difficult if you don't have any way of knowing in the context of `Entity A` that the user should have created an `Entity B`.  #2 will work, but will not scale well if you have hundreds of users sitting there polling.